# Getting typed items from a collection of objects - how to keep track of type?

Tags: c#, class

I instantiate my class ***firedragon***. I store it in a public List collection that holds ***objects***.

```
List<object> currentEnemies = new List<object>();
```

I want to grab that list item,

```
currentEnemies[0]
```

and convert it back into my class. I just don't know how to do that. Can anyone explain to me how to do that, or a better way to store my data?

NOTE: The reason why I am using a list that holds objects is because I have many different classes that may be stored in the list.

Comment: `var firedragon = currentEnemies[0] as FireDragon;`

Comment: Thanks for your help! =-D

Comment: It's not useful to store a bunch of different types of objects in a list if the programmer is simply forced to memorize what the actual type is of every object in every position of the list.  Either the list should be of a type that provides all of the functionality that anyone using the list needs of any object in it, or you shouldn't have a list at all, and instead have different variables for each object, because apparently they aren't actually related at all.

Comment: *The reason why I am using a list that holds objects is because I have many different classes that may be stored in the list.* You already recognize the issue, perhaps look into polymorphism to make your life easier. I am sure they share some sort of common functionality.

Comment: How do you know item at index 0 is a FireDragon?

Comment: because for now I will only be storing one variable. But soon, in the future, I will be storing more.

Comment: @CheyMoore If you're just storing one variable, then you don't need a list.  If you're going to be storing more later, then the question stands, how will you know which item is of what type?

Comment: Perhaps you should store each variable with its own name. It's not like you're saving space or anything by putting them in a list.

Answer (score 3):

One way of handling this is with [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). You could implement a common handler for `currentEnemies` like,

```
foreach (var enemy in currentEnemies) 
{
    switch (enemy) 
    {
        case FireDragon dragon:
            UpdateDragon(dragon);
            break;
        case Bulbasaur plant:
            BeAdorable(plant);
            break;
        // and so on... 
    }
}
```

If you have just a handful of types, and won't have much more in the future (consider this carefully), this isn't too bad, but gets horribly cumbersome quickly.

Ideally, you should look for common elements on your enemies, so that you can simplify this. For example, if you have code that moves the enemy in the world every step, they could all implement a common interface,

```
interface IMobile 
{
    (int X, int Y) Move(int x, int y);
    int Speed { get; }
}
```

Then code to handle movement of enemies could be just,

```
var mobiles = new List<IMobile>(); 

// then in other code that can access `mobiles`
foreach (var mobile in mobiles)
{
    mobile.Move(mobile.Speed);
}
```

Comment: "Bulbasaur" -> "BeAdorable". I'm sold :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's a bad idea when you have direct control over the items be inserted and removed from a list to use `object` as the generic type for a List. It sounds like you're building a game, and if you are I would architect it using interfaces and then use [OfType<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) quite a bit.

```
// Anything you want to track in the game
public interface IGameEntity {}
// Anything that opposes a plyaer
public interface IEnemy : IGameObject {}
// Anything used to do Physical Harm
public interface IWeapon : IGameObject {}
// Anything that can be collected for a purpose (wood, gold, etc)
public interface IResource : IGameObject {}
```

I'm honestly not sure if a *red dragon* would be much different then a *blue dragon*, I would assume not so I would just create a Dragon class.

```
public class Dragon : IEnemy
{
  public DragonColor Color { get; set; }
}

public enum DragonColor
{
  Red,
}
```

Then you're list is:

```
List<IGameEntity> entities;
```

All dragons are

```
var dragons = entities.OfType<Dragon>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are looking for a solution using composition. Example:

```
public class Enemies { 
  public FireDragon TheDraggon { get; set; } 
  public List<Troll> Trolls { get; set; } 
  /* other enemies that you need to track */
}
```

With this approach you do not have to guess or check what type an instance is within the list of objects.